# filtering before filling a TableAdapter

Tags: c#, .net, database, lambda, dataset

So i have a DataSet to query a table on an Oracle Database. The table is very large and has 3.5 million entries. However later in the code I filter this table on a few hundred entries that are necessary.

```
AgileDataSet agileDataSet = new AgileDataSet();
AgileDataSetTableAdapters.UserDataTableAdapter userDataTableAdapter = new AgileDataSetTableAdapters.UserDataTableAdapter();
userDataTableAdapter.Fill(agileDataSet.UserData);

var l=agileDataSet.UserData.Where(x=>x.ID==1234);
```

Due to the large amount of entries the `Fill()` method takes forever. Is there a way to add a conditions to the fill method at runtime. Adding a permanent `WHERE` clause to the TableAdapter's SQL Statement in the DataSet Designer is not an option, because I do not know beforehand which elements are needed.

Comment: ok so I found out that there is a parameterized query which looks promising. However, I cannot seem to create a `IN '@ids'` filter. Where I would load a `string[]` into @ids

Comment: See : https://www.sqlshack.com/implement-array-like-functionality-sql-server/?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I implemented a hacky "solution" and created a new partial class for the TableAdapter. In this class I generated an adapted `Fill`-Function to use whenever I need to get a subset of the whole DBTable in my DataTable

```
partial class UserDataTableAdapter
    {
        public virtual int FillByCICList(AgileDataSet.UserDataDataTable dataTable, List<long> cics)
        {
            this.CommandCollection[0].CommandText += String.Format(" WHERE vu.C_IC IN ({0})", String.Join(", ", cics));
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
            if ((this.ClearBeforeFill == true))
            {
                dataTable.Clear();
            }
            int returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            this.InitCommandCollection();
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
```

This function takes a list of c_ics as additional input and adds a where condition to the base commanttext used for the standard fill function.

Calling it would look sth like this:

```
List<long> c_ics = new List<long>{224,484,966,695,918};
userDataTableAdapter.FillByCICList(agileDataSet.UserData, c_ics);
```

I am sure that there is a better solution to this, but that is all I got so far